# Blog posts for custom post type only

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I registered a custom post type called movies. When I add a new movie the permalink for a movie looks like this: `site.com/movies/movie-title`.

Now I'd like to add news about this movie, but only about this movie and I want the permalink to look like this: `site.com/movies/movie-title/news/post-title`.

I want my blog posts to be specific to my custom post type (`movies`). Is it possible to do? I tried specific categories but the permalink is not how I'd like it to be, it's misleading.

Can anyone point me in the right side? Oh and I'd really like to avoid plugins ;)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a little more information, on, how you see your post structure working.
Do you plan on making a post/page for the movie and a separate post/page for news etc?

Comment: I will have an index page for movies (page w/ loop only for movie post type) `site.com/movies/` and I will have a page for movie news where all the news will be displayed for the current movie: `site.com/movies/movie-title/news/`

Comment: You'd need to implement custom rewrite rules and filter post type link generation for this. How are you planning on associating news articles with movies?

Comment: I want news for a specific movie only. For example, on "Avengers" movie page I want to have news section about this movie for ex. "Robert Downey Jr. caught filming new Iron Man in New York". I thought about adding specific categories for every movie, but this is not ideal as the permalinks are misleading and I have to create a category for each movie and then assign it to the post and all that. Is there a cleaner way to do this instead of kind of 'hackily' rewriting the url? Thanks!